# SQL Server : how to run a stored procedure at the end of each calendar month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to execute a stored procedure at the end of each calendar month. it should take end of the current month as finish and end of previous month as start date.

Here examples:

```
exec my_report @ReportStartDate = '20140731', @ReportEndDate='20140831'
exec my_report @ReportStartDate = '20140131', @ReportEndDate='20131231'
exec my_report @ReportStartDate = '20140228', @ReportEndDate='20140131'
```

My aim is to store results in a table. So I need to create a new stored procedure to call the current stored procedure.

I could not find to schedule the `my_report` stored procedure. So I create a new stored procedure. My aim is to call `caller_sp` on each day and check the dates inside the caller stored procedure.

Here my caller stored procedure. I have good knowledge of oracle but I an new to SQL Server.

1. Is there a way to schedule `my_report` at the end of each calendar month and send begin and end dates.
2. Is there a decent version of my code below

Code:

```
declare @reportstartyear VARCHAR(4) = null
declare @ReportEndDate DATETIME = null
declare @ReportStartDate DATETIME = null

if month(getdate()) = '01' 
Begin
    if DAY(getdate()) = '31' 
    Begin
        set @reportstartyear = year(getdate())-1
        set @ReportStartDate = cast(@reportstartyear + '1231' as Datetime) 

        exec [LTR].[LetterOfGuaranteeProceedsReport] 
             @ReportStartDate, @ReportEndDate = cast(select getdate())
    end
end
else if month(getdate())='02' 
begin
    if year(getdate())%4=0
    begin 
        if day(getdate())='29'
        begin
            set @reportstartyear=year(getdate())
            set @ReportStartDate=cast(@reportstartyear+'0131' as Datetime) 
            exec [LTR].[LetterOfGuaranteeProceedsReport] @ReportStartDate,@ReportEndDate=cast(select getdate())
        end
    end
end
    else if day(getdate())='28'
    begin
        set @reportstartyear=year(getdate())
        set @ReportStartDate=cast(@reportstartyear+'0131' as Datetime) 
        exec [LTR].[LetterOfGuaranteeProceedsReport] @ReportStartDate,@ReportEndDate=cast(select getdate())
    end

else if month(getdate())='03' 
begin
    if day(getdate())='31'
    begin 
        if year(getdate())%4=0
        begin
            set @reportstartyear=year(getdate())
            set @ReportStartDate=cast(@reportstartyear+'0229' as Datetime) 
            exec [LTR].[LetterOfGuaranteeProceedsReport] @ReportStartDate,@ReportEndDate=cast(select getdate())
        end
        else 
        begin
            set @reportstartyear=year(getdate())
            set @ReportStartDate=cast(@reportstartyear+'0228' as Datetime) 
            exec [LTR].[LetterOfGuaranteeProceedsReport] @ReportStartDate,@ReportEndDate=cast(select getdate())
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script seems a bit complicated

```
DECLARE @ReportStartDate date, @ReportEndDate date

-- for sqlserver 2012
SELECT 
  @ReportStartDate = EOmonth(getdate(), -1),
  @ReportEndDate = EOmonth(getdate())

-- for earlier versions
SELECT 
  @ReportStartDate = dateadd(month, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), -1),
  @ReportEndDate =  dateadd(month, datediff(m, -1, getdate()), -1)

EXEC my_report @ReportStartDate, @ReportEndDate
```

To execute the job the last day of every month:

Create a job, then find and pick

Under frequency:

Occurs: Monthly
The Last - Day - of every 1 month

Answer (score 1):

Here my script. I changed to a SP. It works fine. Thanks every one

```
declare
@ReportStartDate DATETIME=EOmonth(getdate(), -1),
@ReportEndDate DATETIME=EOmonth(getdate())

if @ReportEndDate=getdate()
Begin

insert into report_log (col1,
col2,
col3
) exec Report @ReportStartDate, @ReportEndDate,@username=null,@LanguageId=null

update report_log set reportstartdate=@ReportStartDate, reportenddate=@ReportEndDate  where reportenddate is null
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it a lot.

If you're using a modern SQL Server, you have the `EOMONTH` function, to get the last day of the month.

If your SQL Server is older, you can do a little trick: use `DATEADD` function to add 1 day to the current deta (`getdate()`), and compare the month (using the `MONTH` function). If it's the same month, it wasn't the last day of the month. If it's a different month, that's because it was the last day of the month.

References:

- [EOMONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx)
- [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am surely late for this question and I may post the answer out of the context a little bit. But as @JotaBe said (in older version in my case) you can know if you are in new month (In case you have script that run reports of month -1) in this simple way.

```
declare @cDate as date = getDate(), @comDate as Date;
set @comDate = DATEADD(day, -1, @cDate)
if DATEPART(MONTH, @cDate) > DATEPART(month, @comDate)
    print 'Different month'
else
    print 'same month'
```

Inside the if you can fine tune to whatever you want (steps in jobs, etc)